# Nodejs OLE-COM server

Tags: node.js, windows

I am using `win32ole` to access `COM-OLE` (automation) bindings inside a windows PC such as excel, word etc.

Now what I want is to implement a `COM-OLE` server using nodejs. I can't seem to find any nodejs module that supports these.

In the end, I only need to expose `COM-OLE` objects/interfaces to any applications running inside the PC so that they can access my application.

Thanks and BTW, I am using Electron.js.

Answer (score 2):

Since win32ole only appears to operate as a client, you're stuck either:

- Implementing your own COM server in C++ ([nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) helps with the node glue)
- [Writing a COM server in .NET](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+com+server) and using [edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) for the node glue.